# mongodb 2.6 mongos start up failed

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to run mongodb 2.6, everything followed my 2.4 version setup steps.
but when I start mongos I got the following problems and just cannot make it.

```
2014-04-24T03:38:31.001+0800 [mongosMain] SyncClusterConnection connecting to [192.168.0.1:27018]
2014-04-24T03:38:31.002+0800 [mongosMain] SyncClusterConnection connecting to [192.168.0.2:27018]
2014-04-24T03:38:31.002+0800 [mongosMain] SyncClusterConnection connecting to [192.168.0.3:27018]
2014-04-24T03:38:31.066+0800 [mongosMain] scoped connection to 192.168.0.1:27018,192.168.0.2:27018,192.168.0.3:27018 not being returned to the pool
2014-04-24T03:38:42.183+0800 [mongosMain] waited 11s for distributed lock configUpgrade for upgrading config database to new format v5
2014-04-24T03:38:53.288+0800 [mongosMain] waited 22s for distributed lock configUpgrade for upgrading config database to new format v5
2014-04-24T03:39:04.394+0800 [mongosMain] waited 33s for distributed lock configUpgrade for upgrading config database to new format v5
2014-04-24T03:39:15.500+0800 [mongosMain] waited 44s for distributed lock configUpgrade for upgrading config database to new format v5
2014-04-24T03:39:26.604+0800 [mongosMain] waited 55s for distributed lock configUpgrade for upgrading config database to new format v5
2014-04-24T03:39:37.709+0800 [mongosMain] waited 66s for distributed lock configUpgrade for upgrading config database to new format v5
```

Waited for new format v5?
What's that?

Answer (score 1):

There was a [full set of instructions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6-upgrade/#upgrade-sharded-clusters) for the 2.6 upgrade that you don't seem to indicated that you have followed.

In particular are the instructions that indicate you need to process the [**`--upgrade`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongos/#cmdoption--upgrade) option by launching a single `mongos` instance while the balancer is switched off:

> Start a single 2.6 mongos instance with the configDB pointing to the cluster’s config servers and with the --upgrade option.
>
> To run a mongos with the --upgrade option, you can upgrade an existing mongos instance to 2.6, or if you need to avoid reconfiguring a production mongos instance, you can use a new 2.6 mongos that can reach all the config servers.

```
mongos --configdb <config servers> --upgrade
```

As noted there, on completion the following messages should be emitted:

```
upgrade of config server to v5 successful
Config database is at version v5
```

So there is an intended upgrade process for the config servers that it would appear you have not followed yet. The full process is in the link at the top of this answer.

Also have a look at the [compatibility changes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6-compatibility/) list which has some additional considerations with replica sets and sharding that might possibly apply in your situation.